# Define max. column width in CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

So far I got the grid working as intended.

But I want the columns to have a `max-width` of `150px`, while retaining the smallest width possible.

How can I achieve this and ideally drop the fixed amount of 4 columns to "as many columns as may fit"?

```css
.grid {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  gap: 22px 44px;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
}

.item {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Very long text which should wrap</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set that `max-width` on the direct child.

```css
.grid {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  gap: 22px 44px;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
}

.item {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Very long text which should wrap</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
</div>
```

grid-auto-flow might be what you look for but it will not wrap into rows i guess:

```css
.grid {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column ;
  gap: 22px 44px; 
}

.item {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  min-width:max-content;
  max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Very long text which should wrap</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
  <div class="item">Short Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think about this obvious solution…
Do you also have an idea how to make column count flexible?

Comment: yes , i think the use of grid-auto-flow will do. i'll make another snippet.

Comment: Since I need the wrapping, I will calculate the column count via JS.